# How do you connect to Hypixel on Xbox?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

If you can, how do you do it because I've been looking for a way to play hypixel skyblock on my Xbox one for a while now. I have a mobile device if I need it.

Comment: you cannot access hypixel from bedrock edition/without a java edition account, it is required to log into the server as hypixel is not a bedrock edition server. This is not very difficult to find out.

Comment: i dont have a computer so i didnt know

Comment: can i make a java account then get into the server on bedrock?

Comment: I think you can using geysermc however java accounts arent cheap and im not 100% sure how to do it. Its also possible that it could result in anticheats not being too happy and end in a ban due to some bedrock features falling under hacked client territory in java edition.

Comment: hm are they? why cant i just make one on my friends computer when he already has minecraft?

Comment: you could use your friends account, but you would basically have to share it, not to mention that sorta breaks mojangs tos

Comment: no, i will just make another on his pc, not using his

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121047/discussion-between-topcode-and-parkerdaboss216).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must've heard of [GeyserMC](https://geysermc.org).

Unfortunately, due to the implementation of Hypixel anti-cheat, you **should not** connect to Hypixel via Geyser. As per the time of posting, you *still* cannot move in Bedrock Edition. You can connect, but you won't be able to do anything meaningful.

Furthermore, in terms of game balance and feature disparities:

- Bedrock has a further hit distance, allowing you to interact with things further than vanilla Java players can.
- Bedrock movement has extremely high inertia (how fast you go from moving to stopped), whereas in Java, it is lower, especially when flying.
- You can't click links in chat, which Hypixel uses a lot of, and commands are sent in a different way to servers.
- Not all behaviour in Java exists in Bedrock, for example: Buttons have no hitboxes in Java, but do in Bedrock. Entity cramming and physics are also slightly different between the two.

And: Hypixel has publicly stated that even though it isn't banned, any automated bans or false positives from this will be treated as if it was a banned mod. (Basically use at your own risk)

Oh, and you need a Java Edition account too.